# koala response times. 20 seconds waiting response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I'm new with `Rubyonrails` and `Koala gem` and I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. I've been tuning my code to the minimun expression but the problem persist. Then I tried to do the same without koala gem, but the problem persisted.

This is the code:

```
require 'koala'
require 'open-uri'


puts Time.now

@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new
resp = @graph.graph_call("cocacola", {}, "get", {})
puts resp

puts Time.now

coke_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola"
response = open coke_url
response = JSON.parse response.read
puts response.inspect

puts Time.now
```

I have to wait always 21 seconds the Facebook's response. If I put the https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola on my browser, the response is instantaneous ¿is not the same?

thanks

Comment: Interesting problem.  What happens if you put more Time.now() calls after the 'open' call and the JSON.parse call?  Which one is taking the time?  If the open call is taking the time, you could see exactly what is happening with Wireshark or TCPdump.  With a 20 second timeout, I have often seen DNS lookups as the cause.  Maybe a miscuonfigured primary server which finally times out allowing the secondary, but dumping the packets will tell for sure.

Comment: Do you get the same delay using graph explorer? You can set a limit on it- some requests are for a bunch of data, and that does get bounced around Facebook servers a lot, which takes time. The more specific the query, the better response time. But this will be time on Graph Explorer, not Koala. Koala really doesn't have any overhead above and beyond the time it takes to get Facebook's Graph calls.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Koala in my application and did not have such experience. The only difference is that I don't use it anonymously. Instead I created an app and I'm using an access token to access the Facebook API. This might be the root cause, as I've found [this post](http://planet.infowars.com/uncategorized/why-facebook-is-slow-death-to-anonymous) that also seems relates.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 

In my original code I'm using an access token with a facebook application, and I had this slow responses. I have put this code to minimize the lines.

Anyway, if you put the same url (https://graph.facebook.com/Ferrari) directly in the web browser, without being logged in, the response is instantaneously. In my code, when I am trying the last four lines (not using koala) supposedly would be the same. But I have to wait for 21 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it was a DNS problem  (thanks jpgeek).

When I did just a GET request to any website, the response was after 21 seconds, but using the IP of the same website, the response was instantaneously.

I found on google the solution: http://www.mikeperham.com/2010/02/10/asynchronous-dns-resolution/

I have use this personal solution in Gemfile (I'm not sure if it's the best):

```
group :development do
    require 'resolv'
    require 'resolv-replace'
end
```

Now it's working fine!